# Página não para de carregar quando uso exec no WAMP

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Eu preciso fazer um script PHP que execute um programa no servidor, porém a página não para de carregar, é como se ele estivesse esperando o processo ser terminado.

Já fui no services.msc e coloquei o processo do apache para poder interagir com a minha desktop, porém ele vai para outra sessão, como se não fosse a minha.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
<?php
    exec('C:\\teste.exe');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação da função `exec()`](https://www.php.net/function.exec), o PHP aguarda o término da execução do comando, pois o valor retornado pela função `exec()` é a última linha dessa mesma execução.

Comment: Certo, e o que você recomenda que eu use para iniciar um programa em ambiente windows?

Comment: Tente chamar a seguinte função: `pclose(popen("start /B C:\\teste.exe", "r"));`

Comment: O script roda e nada acontece, porém se eu boto um arquivo que não existe, o script fica rodando sem parar..

Answer (score 0):

O Exec aguarda o termino do processo para acabar de interpretar o seu código, um exemplo legal para que você entenda seria fazer um teste com o notepad ("Bloco de notas do Windows.");

```
 <?php exec("notepad.exe"); ?>
```

Assim que executar ele irá abrir o bloco de notas, note que a página vai ficar carregando.... assim que você fechar o bloco de notas a execução irá acabar.